# ReactSelect change value with dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got this ReactSelect and would like to change the displayed value with JavaScript DOM

```
<div class="ReactSelect"><Select id="quarter" options={optionsQuarter}/></div>
```

Things like

```
document.getElementById("quarter").value = "..."
```

won't work, so i think that i have to use a onChange function but i dont know how to access that when i change the value in another method?

Comment: You shouldn't be accessing the actual DOM like this. That's what the virtual DOM is for. Can you explain more about what you're trying to accomplish so we can help you?

Comment: Alright. I'm loading a person and want to fill the according fields with the values. The ReactSelect has an list with options and i want to select the option that is equal to the quarter of the person and later on you should be able to change the Select and maybe use another option. Hope that helps?

Comment: Can you show your code?